# How do I turn off accent combining in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, i18n

I have English Windows 7 Professional with Hungarian keyboard language installed.
The English keyboard layout works as expected, but for the Hungarian layout some kind of "accent combining" is activated.

The effect of this ^+o becomes ô, ^+a becomes â, etc.

This is not helpful at all, since the accented characters of Hungarian are already mapped to keys, but it's really annoying because I have to type a non-combining character to actually get ^.

Is there any way to turn this "feature" off?

Answer (score 9):

### How to create a custom keyboard layout on Windows 7

1. Get [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665) as noted by @bubu.
2. Start Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator
   [image]
3. We're going to load an **existing keyboard**
   [image]
4. And **Hungarian** it is!
   [image]
5. The accent characters seem to only be available on the Hungarian layout when <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is pressed. So let's view that layout.
   [image]
6. Right-click one of the accent keys you want to change. And **uncheck** the option **Set as dead key**.
   [image]
7. Confirm your choice by clicking **OK**.
   [image]
8. The key has now become a *regular* key and will behave like any of the *normal* letters. Repeat this process for all other keys you want to change.
9. Export your new keyboard layout.
   [image]
10. When asked to review your layout properties, confirm and adjust them to your liking. When you're done, press **OK**.
    [image]
11. You will now get a folder with an installer package for your keyboard layout.
    Install it and you will be able to select your new keyboard layout from the system dialog.
    [image]
12. This is the dialog where you would usually select your keyboard layout. You can even see **my** customized layout *German - Programmer* which is a customized German layout without dead keys (the same thing you want to achieve).
    [image]

<s>A word of advice though! Using custom keyboard layout can have some undesirable effects.

For example, when using RDP to connect to another Windows machine, that machine will not know your keyboard layout and switch to English.

Before I used my custom layout, the other machines would happily adapt to German layout.</s>

If you have issues with your keyboard layout being switched around during RDP sessions after using this procedure, please see: [How can I stop the remote computer from changing my keyboard layout?](https://superuser.com/questions/426356/how-can-i-stop-the-remote-computer-from-changing-my-keyboard-layout)

It's still worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Those keys are called "dead keys" -- they don't output anything until you press a second key (which should combine to create a new character).

You can just press space after inputting one of those. (this solution works in X11, Windows and OS X)

Comment: That's the problem! I can't type normally, if I have to press an extra key every now and then. The point is to disable the whole thing competely.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided Oliver Salzburg didnt fix the character accent combining for me. Have a look at this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G015Lna65hs.

This fixed my problem. What kept going wrong was that I needed to first set the default input language to US and then remove the wrong keyboard for good measure.

Comment: You should translate the instructions to your answer, in case the video is ever taken down. Additionally, it might appear as though you are attempting to drive traffic, which is not permitted.