# How can I stop the remote computer from changing my keyboard layout?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

Whenever I open an RDP connection to a remote machine, that machine will be using the English (EN) keyboard layout and I have to constantly switch it back to German.

I use a customized keyboard layout on my workstation and this layout is not present on the remote machine. I assume this to be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Neno Loje](http://blog.nenoloje.com/2010/06/when-using-remote-desktop-keyboard.html) mentions this issue (and the solution) in his blog.

In the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
```

Create a new DWORD value `IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout` and give it the value `1`.

That should be sufficient to solve your problem. However, there are some known problems with certain Windows versions, as discussed in these knowledgebase articles:

#### Windows XP

- [The IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout registry entry does not work on a Windows XP-based computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924271)

#### Windows Server 2003

- [The IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout registry entry has no effect in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842136)
- [The terminal server IME keyboard layout differs from the client computer when you remotely log on to a Windows Server 2003 SP1-based terminal server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917910)

In addition to that, [Remko Weijnen](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/12/27/terminal-server-remote-keyboard-layout/) explains on his blog how to even adjust the keyboard profile on the login page.

> If you want to change the keyboard layout that is used before logging in (“at the logon screen”) you need to modify the key `HKEY_USER\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`:
>
> In the screenshot above the locale id 0413 (Dutch) but you can even add more than one entry and cycle between them with ALT-SHIFT.
>
> A description of the Locale ID’s (LCID’s) can be found in [kb 262283](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262283).

Comment: Which computer are you meant to do this on?!!!

Comment: @ColonelPanic: The remote/target machine