# Sync remote desktop and local system keyboard layout

Tags: remote-desktop, keyboard-layout, windows-server-2012-r2

For context, I need to type in two languages with different keyboard layouts.
When using a remote desktop, I would like the remote system to use what ever layout is currently active on my own system, even if I change it later.

Using `IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout` from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/426356/how-can-i-stop-the-remote-computer-from-changing-my-keyboard-layout), I can get the remote system to use the layout I'm currently using when I'm connecting to the remote. However, it doesn't allow me to keep the two in sync.

Ideally, both the remote and local machine would sync the active keyboard layout and changing it on one would also update it on the other. But a one-way update from the host to the remote would suffice as well.

Does a setting exist for something like this or is there an application I can use for this?